# How to set default empty in query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql

So I have this Query:

```
   var list = (from x in xList 
                 join a in AList on x.commonfield equals a.commonfield
                 join b in BList on x.newCommonField equals b.newCommonField
                 from c in Clist.Where(p=>p.connectorID==x.connectorID).DefaultifEmpty()
                                select new { x, a.DesiredFieldFromA, b.DesiredFieldFromB,c.name}).ToList();

    list.ForEach(el =>
                    {
                        el.x.DesiredFieldFromA= el.DesiredFieldFromA;
                        el.x.DesiredFieldFromB= el.DesiredFieldFromB ;
                        el.x.Name=el.name;
                    });
    return list.Select(p=>p.x);
```

when I do :

```
select new { x, a.DesiredFieldFromA, b.DesiredFieldFromB,c.name}).ToList();
```

Question#1: How can I tell it that it should still show me the record ... but put string.empty if the name field is null. 
Something along :

```
select new { x, a.DesiredFieldFromA, b.DesiredFieldFromB,c.name??string.Empty}).ToList();
```

Question#2: How can i tell it that even if "connectorID" is null .. i still need it to show the x record
Thanks in advance!

**Solution for #1 and #2 was as follows :**

```
from c in Clist.Where(p=>p.connectorID==x.connectorID).DefaultifEmpty()
                                select new { x, a.DesiredFieldFromA, b.DesiredFieldFromB,name= (c==null) ?"Not Defined": c.name}).ToList();
```

Comment: For Question #2, are you looking for something akin to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: yes... but using that gives me alot of duplicated of the records that have connectorID =null . I'm working for a fix atm. :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Question #1, try this:

```
select new { 
    x, 
    a.DesiredFieldFromA, 
    b.DesiredFieldFromB, 
    name = c.name ?? string.Empty
}).ToList();
```

You need to specify the name "name" so you can use your expression to assign it.

For question #2, refer to [jonnyGold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11138866/93652).

Answer (score 1):

For Question #2, change:

```
from c in Clist.Where(p=>p.connectorID==x.connectorID).DefaultidEmpty()
```

to:

```
from c in Clist.Where(p=>p.connectorID==x.connectorID || x.connectorID == null)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.As for my decision to accept the answer, I actually flipped a coin, and you lost.But in your honor I'm gonna raise my gaymeter by listening to JohnnYGold: http://bit.ly/tsC585.Thanks again !

Comment: No problemo, @Noobsyke.  For the record, that is not me in that video ;)